# Gradle Jib : Additional build artifacts generated by Jib

Tags: gradle, jib

I have a SpringBoot(2.6.2)/Gradle(7.3.3) application. I am using Jib(3.1.4) to create the docker image. After the image is created and pushed to the registry (successfully), my build would fail with this error -

```
java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: <Project-Dir>\build\jib-image.digest
```

After much trial-and-error and some help from [this documentation](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/jib/blob/master/jib-gradle-plugin/README.md#additional-build-artifacts), I figured out how to make the error go away. What was needed on my build.gradle was this -

```
jib {

    outputPaths.digest = "${buildDir}/jib-image.digest"
    outputPaths.imageId = "${buildDir}/jib-image.id"
    outputPaths.imageJson = "${buildDir}/jib-image.json"

}
```

This forces these files to be created in the specified directories.

My questions are -

1. What are these files?
2. Why is my build not able to create them under my project diretory (as is the default)?
3. Why don't I see any discussion on these files anywhere?
4. Is there another way to avoid this error?

Comment: You are on Windows, right? Is `<Project-Dir>` literally what you see in the log? (If so, no wonder that it will fail.) But I assume you just replaced the actual file path prefix with the string `<Project-Dir>` to hide your personal directory structure, right? Is there anything particular about the full path, e.g., whitespace, non-ascii character? Is it an absolute path? Does it have a drive letter (e.g., C:\)?

Comment: Yes. I am on WIndows.  As you assumed, I replaced the actuall full ptath with <Project-Dir> to hide my directory structure. Now that you mentioned it, my path may be the issue. It is rather long with some white spaces - "E:\Git\Java Projects\Web Applications\hubitat". Let me try by removing the white spaces. Thank you very much

Comment: Try to find the minimum path that works by trail-and-error. If you think this is a bug, please file an issue on the Jib repo.